# Closing lid turns off display

Tags: laptop, battery, sleep, power-management

When my laptop is running on battery, my display turns off whenever I close the lid. This occurs even though I have gone into the power options and changed the settings to "do nothing" when I close the lid, when on battery and when plugged in. When the laptop is plugged in, the display pops back on immediately when I re-open the lid. On battery though, the screen remains dark. It wouldn't be such a big deal except when I re-open the lid, I often have to press the power button repeatedly to get the display to turn back. Even then, it's a mix of pressing the power button and tapping on the touchpad five or six times. Any ideas on what's going on here? Operating system is Windows 10. I've had this same problem with other laptops. They've all been HPs. Don't know if that's part of the issue or not. I just saw your post, Scott, about Windows not honoring your power setting to do nothing when you close the lid. Did you try to proposed solution to modify the registry settings?

Comment: Are you certain the laptop isn't simply going to sleep when you close the lid? You can determine this by looking in the system event log for a power event reporting that the system resumed from sleep. This would be logged around the time when you open the lid back up.

Comment: Yes, I do think it's going to sleep but the question is... why? I specified in the settings that I want the laptop to "do nothing" when I close the lid.

Comment: *What operating system?* … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop ignores power settings, closing lid always sleeps/hibernates; why?](https://superuser.com/q/823090/150988)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent screen turning off when lid is closed](https://superuser.com/q/1097780/150988).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Windows honor my setting to do nothing when I close the lid of my computer](https://superuser.com/q/1324782/150988).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8: How to Lock (not sleep) laptop on lid close?](https://superuser.com/q/496295/150988)